# Data from SqlDataReader not displaying in else statement

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, sqldatareader

I have a `SqlDataReader` that I'm pulling data from. I'm trying to display different messages to the user based on data from the reader. When my if statement returns true the data is displayed correctly when the if statement returns false I get a lengthy error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    string key = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetDetails", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserKey", key);

    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();

        getBidNumber = reader["SelectedBid"].ToString();
        getCompanyName = reader["CompanyName"].ToString();
        getUserKey = reader["MembershipUserKey"].ToString();
        getMerchantKey = reader["MerchantKey"].ToString();
        getMerchantName = reader["MerchantName"].ToString();

        this.DataBind();

        if (getBidNumber != null)
        {
            lblBidSelected.Text = "Congratulations you have selected #" + getBidNumber + " from " + getCompanyName + ". Click here to review you bid details.";
        }

        else
        {
            lblNoBidSelected.Text = "You have not selected a processor. Please <a href='bids-visit.aspx?mkey=" + getMerchantKey + "'>click here</a> to review your bids.";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblError.Text = "There was an error " + err;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the much more readable `HasRows` property of the `SqlDataReader`, like this:

```
if (reader.HasRows) 
{
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        // Do your reading logic here
        getBidNumber = reader["SelectedBid"].ToString();
        getCompanyName = reader["CompanyName"].ToString();
        getUserKey = reader["MembershipUserKey"].ToString();
        getMerchantKey = reader["MerchantKey"].ToString();
        getMerchantName = reader["MerchantName"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Note: This makes it very obvious as to why or why not any data was processed by your reading logic.

UPDATE:

Change your `if-else` logic to this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getBidNumber))
{
    lblBidSelected.Text = "Congratulations you have selected #" + getBidNumber + " from " + getCompanyName + ". Click here to review you bid details.";
}
else
{
    lblNoBidSelected.Text = "You have not selected a processor. Please <a href='bids-visit.aspx?mkey=" + getMerchantKey + "'>click here</a> to review your bids.";
}
```

Note: A `string` will initialize to an empty string, not null, and `ToString()` will not return null; so using the `IsNullOrEmpty()` method to check for a value is more in line with your approach.

Comment: This takes care of my error, but I still can't seem to get data to my else statement when my condition in the if statement is false.

Comment: Why not just `if (reader.Read())`? That's shorter, and certainly readable enough.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - `.Read()` returns a Boolean, but can you tell that from the name of the method? Contrast that with `.HasRows`, it is pretty obvious that true or false is the answer from that name.

Comment: @brandozz - see `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Comment: This worked, the problem I was having was an incorrect join in my stored procedure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @brandozz - no problem, good luck with the rest of your coding. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since your are inside `else` it means:

`reader==null -> getMerchantKey = reader["MerchantKey"].ToString()==null`

-> you get your error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not inside the `else` block. The exception is thrown earlier, at this line:

```
getBidNumber = reader["SelectedBid"].ToString();
```

The reason it throws there is because the call to `reader.Read()` did not produce any results. It only *seems* like the problem is at the `else` block, because if the call to `reader.Read()` succeeded the `if` condition would always test to `true`. What you really want is code like this:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    getBidNumber = reader["SelectedBid"].ToString();
    getCompanyName = reader["CompanyName"].ToString();

    lblBidSelected.Text = "Congratulations you have selected # ... "
}
else
{
    //You'll need to change your error message, because the merchant key is unknown
    blNoBidSelected.Text = "You have not selected a processor. ... "
}
```

Comment: What about my condition in the if statement? if (getBidNumber != null)

Comment: @brandozz `.ToString()` will **never** return `null`. If the value of the column is `null`, `.ToString()` will return an empty string. So if the call to `reader.Read()` succeeds, that `if()` condition will _always_ be `true`. It's impossible for the current code to ever reach the `else` block.

Comment: Joel, does it return an Empty string?

Comment: It doesn't seem like my if statement is always returning true, if that were the case then my congratulations message would display. What I'm getting is either nothing displayed at all or text displayed without data from my reader.

Comment: When you have text without data from your reader, that's empty strings where you were expecting `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error before reaching the if statement probably because your query returns no row. Check reader.Read() return value before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

First of all initialise like this

```
string getBidNumber =null;
```

and when do string conversion check reader["SelectedBid"] is null or not.

```
if(reader["SelectedBid"] !=null)
{
getBidNumber = reader["SelectedBid"].ToString();
}
```

Rest of code all same. Best of luck

Comment: I did try this but I just can't get data into the else statement.